# Can I torrent a dvd and still try ubuntu

Tags: boot

I torrented the 64bit edition for my pc but the only option at boot was install ubuntu. I am now torrenting the 32 bit hoping it has try ubuntu option.

Help?

Comment: Make sure you are downloading [one of these torrents](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads), and not some random torrent you found online.

Answer (score 1):

"Trying" Ubuntu should be the first option on the list. Just let Ubuntu bootup without pressing anything and it should default to trial mode.

Make sure you don't accidentally have the 'alternative' dvd.